# Bootstrap border issue in IE7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

I'm using Bootstrap's responsive grid to layout an HTML page. Though the form looks perfect in Chrome, in IE7, when I use a border, the box model will jump down in the fluid.

**Example:**

*HTML:*

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="box span3"></div>
    <div class="box span3"></div>
    <div class="box span3"></div>
    <div class="box span3"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.box{
   border:5px solid red;
}
```

This HTML and CSS works fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE 8, 9, and 10.

Why, in IE7 does the last span jump down?

I know this is an IE bug with box model, do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: See if this is useful : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?37633-IE-7-Border-Problem

Comment: still not work !! any idea !! thanks

Comment: Is it just an IE7-specific issue? Can you confirm whether it works in IE8 or other IE versions?

Answer (score 0):

add this script in page for IE 7

```
 <!--[if IE 7]>
<style>
    .row-fluid .span3{
        width:22.80% !important;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```